# Сбросить значения по умолчанию тегов header, footer, main, article итд

Tags: html, css

Создал страницу, используя дивы и стили, сейчас хочу задокументировать код и привести к более универсальному виду ( в моем понимании). Так вот когда применил хедэр, футер, артикл, то немного изменился вид страницы, сместилось содержание, с край на центр и тд. В начале css файла прописал

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Как можно сбросить значения по умолчанию для вышеперечисленных тегов?

Comment: _"В начале css файла прописал"_ Это не просто в начале файла нужно было прописать. Это надо было сделать в первую очередь. Понятно, что сейчас лень исправлять все рамки и отступы ;-)

Comment: Посмотри вот такую статейку на тему "сброса" `css` - https://snipp.ru/html-css/css-reset

Comment: Может выразился не так, имеется в виду, что css файл начать писать со звездочки первым делом, потом вест остальной код

Comment: @Дмитрий, _"... когда применил хедэр..."_ - это что такое?

Comment: использовал сначала дивы. Страницу создал. Все работает, меня устраивает. Теперь решил комментарии написать и блок шапки заключить в тег хедер, подвал - футер. Обернул свой блок в header? подвал - в footer. И немного все съехало

Answer (score 0):

npm install reset-css введи это в терминале, и это сбросит все стили css